# Removing special characters in shell from a json response

Tags: shell, awk

In my shell, I have a JSON response like you can see below. When I am printing, it prints `""` with JSON, but I want to remove them.

```
{
   "Grade": "tenth"
}
```

I am using

```
curl -s "<<API>>"| awk '{print $2;}'
```

Comment: Post the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jq` JSON parser instead of `awk`:

```
curl -s "<<API>>" | jq -r '.Grade'
```

`-r` is the raw mode. It outputs the string without quote.

Comment: I do not want to use JQ,I am able to output using Jq.I am looking to do it in awk or cut .

Comment: So you're looking to something like `awk -F\" 'NF>3{print $4}'`, but this is very fragile and will not resist with complex JSON file. I advise use a JSON parser to get JSON data. FYI awk/sed/cut/etc... are not JSON parsers.

Comment: Thank you ,Yes I was looking for something like this,My JSON is not complex and very simple.